# how to close model dialog using shortcut key "Esc"

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a model dialog, when I click the `Esc` key, it closes the background form. But I want to close the model dialog.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Escape:
            Cancel_Click(Cancel, new EventArgs());
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Printscreen of the dialogs:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  I can't even understand what you're saying.

Comment: Why do you have that ProcessCmdKey? Is it in the form that you want to close or in the parent one? I would Just add a button with the "Exit" text and with the DialogResult property set to Cancel. Finally setting the form's property CancelButton to this button will result in the modal form closure on the ESC key

Comment: thanks its helpful.